# msi installer which run sql code during installation

Tags: windows-installer

Inside my web application (asp.net C#) I'm added web setup app. With this web setup I need to do two things:

1. copy files into application located on IIS

2. run three insert statements during installation

I have problems with the second point and don't know how to fix it or debug it.
Inside custom actions I already added dll file (Primary output) on Install folder and this is almost all what I found on internet about running SQL scripts during installation. 
Also I need to announce that I override function OnAfterInstall on this way:

```
string connectionString1 = string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=True;", Context.Parameters["db"], Context.Parameters["catalog"]);
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString1))
{

string CommandText = "insert into Sealed (Example) values ('now is OK'); ";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(CommandText, connection);  
com.ExecuteNonQuery();                
}
```

If you know some good tutorial or book, which describe running sql statements during installation, it will help me a lot

Answer (score 2):

If your files are loaded into an IIS application, why not supply the INSERT sql via some XML files, then have a piece of code in your application that checks a folder for xml files that contain scripts that your application can run on Application_Start.

You'll need to have a mechanism to ignore them once they have been run, or delete them.

Comment: Thank you Chris, your answer is new approach for me and very logical answer and i will try it probably tomorrow because now it's late and I'm sleepy a bit

Comment: fresh eyes are always a good idea with new stuff. sleep on it. Thanks.

Comment: I agree with you :), just one more thing: is it possible to specify app folder on which I want to copy Primary output? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Windows Installer is an SDK and a Windows platform service but it's not really an MSI authoring tool.  (ORCA doesn't really count.)

Take a look at Windows Installer XML (WiX) or InstallShield.  They both add support for SQL connections and script execution on top on MSI without you having to write it yourself.